# How to get the just inserted row details?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I am using [pg][1] module

[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg to insert data in to postgresql. 
I am running the insert query inside a loop and my logic need the just inserted row details including the primary key id value to move forward. I can't use any other module because of the dependency issue. Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: great choice. just use `inert into... returning *` as select to get all your values

Comment: I didn’t get . Can u explain bit more .

Comment: post your code - I'll tell how you should modify it